# .class expected error

Tags: java

I am trying to write some code to print out a square made up of '*'s. The problem is that I get an error saying '.class expected' after the variable 'int stars'. I'm not sure what this means.

```
class Main
{
public static void main( String args[] )
{


int sqaure = 5;
int line = 1;

while ( line <= sqaure )

int stars = 1;
while ( stars <= square )
{ 
System.out.print( "*" );
stars = stars + 1;
}
System.out.println();
line = line + 1;
}

}
```

Comment: A little indentation highlights the problem.

Comment: You need an IDE with code formatting. Broken indentation would have made this bug obvious.

Comment: Please don't change the question to a completely different one. Reverted it back to the original. If you need more help, open a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You changed your question to a completely different one. This is not really how SO works since the answers that were already here are not answers to your current question anymore.

Now you have a typo in the variable names (`sqaure` vs `square`).

Please use an IDE as it will help you prevent these pesky little errors and can help you learn programming in java.

Comment: I'm sorry, what IDE would you recommend?

Comment: I like Eclipse but Netbeans is also very common. You can of course experiment to see what suits you best

Comment: Choice of IDE is really a personal matter I prefer working on Eclipse while few of my friends won't accept anything other than IDE... Actually it a lot depends upon the project environment and personal conveinance... I would suggest to install (NetBeans and Eclipse both at the beginning and than decide based on ur experience....

Answer (score 6):

now its better

forgot the

```
{}
```

after

```
while ( line <= sqaure )
```

and also you should make the stars declaration more close to beginning

Answer (score 2):

While syntax is

```
while(boolean)
{
//Your code
}
```

`while ( line <= sqaure ) { //yourcode }`

Comment: The brace should go on the same line, and not the next line

Comment: @AlanFoster: Are you sure? Which brace you are referring to?

Answer (score 1):

```
class Main
{
    public static void main( String args[] )
    {

        int square = 5;
        int line = 1;
        int stars = 1;
        while ( line <= square ){
            while ( stars <= square ){ 
                System.out.print( "*" );
                stars = stars + 1;
            }
            System.out.println();
            line = line + 1;
         }
    }

}
```

download eclipse or NetBeans IDE from their sites.. If you are working on Windows even Notepad++ may be helpful (if you are a beginner)